# Clustering Series of Events

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a time-series of events, which I need to cluster in groups. These events do not always come in same amounts: at any given time there can be 1 event and on other times there can be n  events.

**Just for reference dataset looks like:**

```
Time | Events
t1   | [A, B, C]
t2   | [B, E, F]
t3   | [B, E, G, H, K]
t4   | [A, B, C, D]
```

**Question:** I am trying to see how many clusters of such events exist based on some sort of similarity. How to solve this problem for both situations when we care for sequence of events at time t and when we do not care in which sequence the events occur at time t (A,B,C is similar to B,C,A).

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! 
1. Can you show any of your attempts to solve this problem? 
2. "I am trying to see how many clusters of such events exist based on some sort of similarity" - Do you want to cluster events? 
A more illustrative example might also help here.

Answer (score 0):

So, affinity propagation will automatically figure out the optimal number of clusters for you (or at least it is supposed to do that).  Check out the link below and try to adapt that to your specific needs.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_affinity_propagation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-affinity-propagation-py

In short, vectorize your specific data and fee that into the algo.  Post back if you get stuck doing that.